# TinyMCE editor with custom HTML tag behavior

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins

I am using the TinyMCE editor in combination with [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) or more precisely [Angular Elements](https://angular.io/guide/elements) to produce HTML with placeholder tags. These placeholder tags are later used to instantiate Angular components. Getting TinyMCE to allow custom HTML tags is easy with the [custom_elements](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#custom_elements) config parameter. Just to be clear, I do not want Web Components inside the editor itself. I am using the text(HTML) that the editor produces in a later stage, not really relevant for this problem. The editor output is perfect as it is. My problem is related to the behaviour of the editor.

I want this

```
<custom-container>
  <custom-item>Item one</custom-item>
  <custom-item>Item two</custom-item>
  <custom-item>Item three</custom-item>
</custom-container>
```

to feel and behave like a regular list.

```
<ul>
  <li>Item one</li>
  <li>Item two</li>
  <li>Item three</li>
</ul>
```

I have tried the following config with some success.

```
{
  custom_elements: 'custom-container,custom-item',
  valid_children: 'custom-container[custom-item]',
  formats: {
    container: { block: 'custom-container', merge_siblings: true, wrapper: true },
  },
}
```

I get stuck within the custom container and can't escape it. I would like `<custom-container>` to behave like `<ul>` and `<custom-item>` to behave like `<li>`. Someone might suggest using the list that is already implemented and simply changing the tag names. I would if I could, but I need the list... -.- I have a feeling that it is possible to achieve my goal with some keyboard commands or event listening, but I have no idea where to start. Help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with custom elements. You can try add ~ at the beginning of each element.

This worked for me.

```
{
  custom_elements: '~custom-container,~custom-item',
  valid_children: 'custom-container[custom-item]',
  formats: {
    container: { block: 'custom-container', merge_siblings: true, wrapper: true },
  },
}
```